# Any Spring conditional annotation whose condition depends on the value of a specific variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring and have started building Web services with Springboot. There is a requirement that says I have to enable / disable a `RestController` based on a value of a specific variable of a Class.

I was looking at all the questions here dealing with `@ConditionalOnExpression` and `@ConditionalOnProperty`, but none of them told me if I could set the condition of a `RestController` on the basis of a value of a variable.

If I have the following class

```
public class CheckCondition {

  public boolean allowed = true;
}
```

what conditional annotation should I use to that will decide the condition on the basis of the class's variable's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write your own conditional class by extending `Condition` interface. Something like this

```
class SomeCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

       //do your logic and return true or false based on some condition
    }
}
```

And then you can use this condition on a class like this

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(value = SomeCondition.class)
public class YourClass{
}
```